# Does the new Gamecube controller work with Gamecube games on a Wii?

Tags: controllers, nintendo-switch, nintendo-gamecube

I was wondering if the new Gamecube controller released with Smash Bros Ultimate would work with GC games on a Wii (like OoT in the Zelda Collector's Edition) since the connector is shaped exactly the same and requires an adapter to be connected to the Switch. Sorry if this is dumb or if this has already been answered but I didn't find anything on the subject. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your Wii has ports for GameCube controllers, yes, the controller will work on the Wii.

According to [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DJX3Y47):

> #### About the product
>
> - Some will always prefer that system's Controller
> - **The Nintendo GameCube Controller also could be used in the Super smash Bros. Brawl for the Wii system**
> - To honor that devoted loyalty to a classic way to play, this is the Super smash Bros. Ultimate Edition GameCube Controller
> - Please note the controller can only be used when the Nintendo Switch console is in TV mode.

Emphasis mine.